# How do I connect to mysql database with password

Tags: mysql, mariadb, php, connectivity

Using PHP 7.4.27 (now using 7.4.29) with MariaDB in xampp

I can access everything using phpmyadmin.  I am using the following on my localhost

```
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
```

I can connect using using root (which has no password)
I can connect using another User with no password
But I cannot connect with this user and password.

I created the user using myphpadmin.  When it did not work, I used this to change the password

```
set password for 'someuser'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('somepwd');
```

But I get

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): 
Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I have just updated my xampp package.  The New Maria DB Version is 10.4.24, but the error is the same.

`show grants for 'username'@'localhost'` shows this (there are 2 databases)

```
Grants for username@localhost
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES, ...
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES, ...
```

Just `show grant` shows

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` ...
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH G...
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Which mariadb version is this (`SELECT VERSION()`)? Using `myphpadmin`, what does `show grants` show for you? What does it show as a php originated query?

Comment: I have updated my post.  The answer to your last question - the error in my post above is what I get from my php code.